# How to get back sudo on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sudo, password, root

I have done this:

```
sudo chown -R myname /usr/
```

and now I can't use the `sudo` command because of this error:

> sudo: must be setuid root

And as I read this means that the owner of this file `/usr/bin/sudo` is not the root. It's my user now because of the chown on the `/usr` folder.

On many forums and blogs people suggest to do this as root:

```
# chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
# chmod 4111 /usr/bin/sudo
```

...but the problem with this is that I need to log in as a root, but I can't because If I write `su` in the terminal the password is wrong (actually I use the password what I added to my user):

```
$ su
Password:
su: Authentication failure
```

So can I get back the `sudo` command?

Edit: My Ubuntu is under Paralells on my Mac OS X.

Comment: What do you mean by "I use the password what I added to my user"? When you use `su`, you will be prompted for **root's password**, not your user's password like with `sudo`. Do you know the root password for this machine?

Comment: No, I never needed to add or modify it, is there a default for it?

Comment: You need to reboot in single user mode. What distribution are you running?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 11.04. How can I reboot in single user mode? :)

Comment: Just curious, but what made you decide to run a `sudo chmod -R cirk:cirk /usr` What were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: A Program what was installed somewhere in /usr/ since I didn't known the exact location of the program I decided to use chown on the entire usr folder, and because I'm a noob I screwed up everything again :P

Comment: Didn't we repeatedly tell you this was a very bad and dangerous idea in an earlier question when you were just talking about `/usr/lib/` ?

Comment: @Shadur That was not an earlier question :)

Comment: Thanks for getting my sodo back up and running; I just had to add the bellow line to fix the final problem. `chown root:root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a similar system that you can use as a guide to see what the correct ownership for all of the files is, then you can boot into rescue mode, drop to a root shell, and manually restore the correct ownership to all of the files in `/usr`.

The quickest way may be to reinstall your OS or restore from backup.

In Ubuntu or similar, then there is no root password by default (the account is disabled), which is why you can't `su`.

Comment: Woah take it easy there, this isn't windows re-installing is not always the easiest or fastest way to do anything and certainly doesn't teach people how to fix problems. In this case all he needs to do is reverse the action he took which can easily be done by mounting the file system up in another environment like a LiveCD or the rescue mode you suggested (distro dependent).

Comment: @Caleb when you completely trash the permissions on an major chunk of the filesystem it is.  He didn't just screw up sudo, presumably he forgot to mention in his post that he used -R ( otherwise it would have only changed the owner of the /usr directory itself and not sudo ).  I also did describe how to reverse the process, but it is a very time consuming and painstaking task.

Comment: This is a case of `chown` not `chmod`. Since everything in the `/usr` folder should be `root:root`, this should be an easy fix, not the painstaking fix that a `chmod` clobber would mean.

Comment: Gosh I just finished installing everything and now I can start it again? :( and yes I forgot to mention I used `-R` too, I edited my question too

Comment: @Caleb not everything in /usr should be root:root.

Comment: @CIRK: As long as you did `chown` and not `chmod` this should be an easy fix without having to re-install. `chmod` is much harder to clean up from and @psusi's advice really only applies to that case.

Comment: Examples? I have a couple of symlinks that are owned guest:root and some stuff in /usr/src that I have manually forced to be owned by my user, but that's not a default configuration. The group ownership might vary more, but luckily @CIRK hasn't seemed to touch that, just the owner.

Comment: @Caleb `chown` resets the setxid bits. There are a few files in `/usr` that aren't owned by the root; more that are in a different group (especially setgid programs in `/usr/bin`).

Comment: @Caleb I suppose there aren't that many.  Obviously it depends on your distribution and what packages you have installed.  On my Ubuntu server here at work, there appear to be two: /usr/bin/at owned by daemon.daemon, and /usr/sbin/uuidd owned by libuuid.libuuid.  I'm pretty sure my desktop at home has several more.  I suppose you are right; he didn't change the group ownership so things aren't nearly as bad.

Comment: I edited your question a little to put the priority on going through and restoring everything (however little or much it ends up being) and reversed my vote. I think @Gilles has the most important bit here that setxid bits need to be fixed and there are a few of those.

Answer (score 12):

Since you have hosed the permissions on the only thing that gives you root level access, you will need some help from OUTSIDE the current software environment to fix this.

I suggest that the easiest way is to boot up a LiveCD for your distro, mount your drive, and change the file permissions using the `chmod` you listed from there.

You could also try booting into single-user mode in order to get a root shell.

Be aware that usually all things in the `/usr/` directory should be owned `root` so you should just be able to do a recursive `chown` to fix whatever you broke. (**Edit:** Per @Gilles comments apparently running `chown` breaks setuid and setgid bits, so you *will* need to manually compare to an existing system to restore all of those once you fix the ownership again.)

However, very **FEW** should be `4111`. That extra one is a special permissions but that makes it execute as root even when run as a user! Only `sudo` and a select few commands should have this permission bit set. *If you didn't run a `chmod` to start with you probably don't need to fix this at all*, all the permissions should already be correct. Don't run a big `chmod` operation without knowing what all the permissions are supposed to be.

Comment: Is it possible if the OS is in a Virtual Machine?

Comment: Yes that makes no difference. You could use runlevel 1 (something you can do at the very beginning of the boot process from grub/lilo or wahtever your bootloader is) or you can setup the VM to use an ISO image of the LiveCD as the boot device.

Comment: aham, well before I reinstall it, I will try your advice :)

Comment: ok I think I'm in the LiveCD, now I need to write this in the terminal? `sudo chown -R root /usr/` ?

Comment: Ya start with that, but not on `/usr` on the LivdCD, you need to mount it somewhere and run against that path, say `/mnt/mydrive/usr`. Then you will need to fix the setuid bit on `/mnt/mydrive/usr/bin/sudo`. Then look through the /usr on the livecd and see if there are any other ownerships other than root. `find /usr -not -uid 0` and change those to match. Then look for things that have different setuid or setgid bits set and make sure those match too. If you have a real Ubunutu system to compare to that would be best.

Comment: ups I already started on /usr , but what do you mean by `mount it somewhere and run against that path`?

Comment: The absolute path `/usr` when you boot to the LiveCD is going to be the files from the CD that are living in RAM. You need to mount your the hard drive from your system and make your changes on that. Something like `mkdir /mnt/mydrive; mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/mydrive` should do the trick if sda1 is the drive where /usr got installed. Then `/mnt/mydrive/usr` is the location you want to work with.

Comment: ahh I can't do it, I've done exactly what your wrote but I don't think that the hard drive what it is using is called sda1 . And I don't really know how to get the name of it.

Comment: Try looking at `dmesg` for clues about any drives that have been recognized. It might be sda3, that's another common thing. Also `fdisk -l /dev/sd[abc]` to list partitions on the first three possible drives, maybe that would give you a clue.

Comment: @Caleb let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/856/discussion-between-cirk-and-caleb)

Comment: well your answer may work, but I can't figure out so I will reinstall it because It was a newly installed OS, so I don't loose much, if I wouldn't bother fixing it I could reinstall it twice since we are talking :)) But thanks very much I learned a lot

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu recovery mode, enter the following commands..This fixed the isssue for me..

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
restart
```

Hope this will fix your problem.( or somebody else's)

I found this one here in this [blog post](http://bitmapcake.blogspot.com/2014/08/linux-fixing-error-sudo-usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is much easier than suggested by other answers. No need to format, reboot or use live CD.

```
su root # then enter your password to switch to root user
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
exit # to get back to the original user
```

This is the easiest way to fix this issue.
Explanation, sudo is corrupted (I know corrupted is the wrong term, but it is not working, so, we need to avoid using sudo)

- Using command 1 **(su root)** , we change user to root without using sudo.
- Using command 2 **(chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo)** , we fix the permissions / ownership of sudo.
- Using command 3 **(exit)** , we get back to the original user.

I have tested this method on Linux mint. Which is a ubuntu like system. Let me know this this method does not work on any other OS. Will update the answer accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: as I understand, by default root account does not have password, so it is impossible to provide password at the first step `su root`, and because `sudo` does not work, it is impossible to set root password

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler than people are making it. Try the following:

1. Instead of trying to log in as root using the broken `su` command, log out as your current user and log in again as root via your normal Display Manager (i.e. login screen).
2. Execute following at the terminal: `chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo`

This should fix the `sudo` command and have you up and running again in no time.

Answer (score 0):

To login as root, without su or sudo, you can use pkexec:

```
pkexec su
```

Now change the files’ permissions:

```
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
chmod 775 /etc/sudoers.d
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/README
```