# Is it safe to chown on /usr/lib?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

Can I do this?

```
sudo chown -R myUsernName /usr/lib
```

I mean can I do this without worrying that my OS will be broken? Or permissions will be screwed up?

Here is the reason why I would like to do it

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752873/node-js-npm-install-fails

and here is why I don't and I came here to ask you guys:

- [How to get back sudo on Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16962/how-to-get-back-sudo-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix  Sorry I misspelled `chown`, do you mean this for `chmod` or `chown`?

Comment: A better question is *why* are you doing this?

Comment: Concur with @Marco - this seems like a tremendously bad idea at /best/, with absolutely no potential benefit that springs to mind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two things:

(1) There is absolutely no advantages for this.  The files in `/usr/lib` are supposed to be owned by root/system, as MANY things on the system which are owned by root are dependent on them.

(2) This is also a very good way to break your system.-

Just to make a point, follow this general rule of thumb:
**If in doubt, don't do it.**

Answer (score 5):

Given that `sudo` is `/usr/bin/sudo` normally, you won't be able to use it after you run that `chown` command: the `sudo` binary owner will be yourself, so you won't get `root` permissions when running it next time.

So *don't* do that.

Comment: This specific answer probably belongs on one of the linked questions... this question refers specifically to `/usr/lib/`

Answer (score 4):

No.

If you don't completely understand the reasons for the permissions of the files on your system, don't change them.

Generally speaking, files outside your home directory or `/tmp` or designated directories for *data* should belong to system users, not to you.

Furthermore, you should not write under `/usr`, with the exception of `/usr/local`: this is reserved for your distribution or package manager. If you want to install a program system-wide, install it under `/usr/local`.

That installation script looks like it's trying to install in the wrong places. If it tries to copy things to `/usr/lib`, it's *broken*. Don't use it. Look for a package for your distribution, or for a better installation script, or better installation instructions. Again, if things end up in `/usr/lib` (as opposed to `/usr/local/lib`) without going through a package manager, the installation process is broken.

Comment: @CIRK: Please note this, what Gilles is saying is true. Anything that tries to run an install to /usr (not /usr/local) NOT through your distributions package manger **IS BROKEN**. Changing the permissions on `/usr` **WILL LIKEWISE BREAK YOUR SYSTEM**. Don't do it. Worst case senario, download the script and edit it to change all the paths to something else before you run it. Best case, find a real package that installs in your user folder or /usr/local.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not safe: the permissions in `/usr/lib` are chosen for two reasons:

- guarding against accidental modification of the system programs, and
- providing privileged access to various features of the system, e.g., using setuid/setgid programs.

You can see the latter using

```
find /usr/lib -type f -perm /7000
```

to search for any program using setuid (4000) or setgid (2000) or sticky bit (1000).  On my Debian7, that shows several files:

```
/usr/lib/eject/dmcrypt-get-device
/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
/usr/lib/kde4/libexec/kdesud
/usr/lib/openssh/ssh-keysign
/usr/lib/libvte9/gnome-pty-helper
/usr/lib/emacs/23.4/x86_64-linux-gnu/movemail
/usr/lib/mc/cons.saver
/usr/lib/libvte-2.90-9/gnome-pty-helper
/usr/lib/utempter/utempter
/usr/lib/pt_chown
/usr/lib/evolution/camel-lock-helper-1.2
/usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

If you change the ownership of those files, they can no longer perform the task for which they are designed.  For instance, `gnome-pty-helper` and `utempter` are used to update the [utmp/wtmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html) feature (providing data for [`w`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/w.1.html) and [`last`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1@@util-linux.html)).

Further reading:

- [Using find -perm to find setuid files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213456/using-find-perm-to-find-setuid-files)