# get back sudo with Putty: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Tags: permissions, putty, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

apparently I messed up too much with my permissions and now I'm getting this while trying to use 'screen' again:

```
/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

If I try: `chown root:root /usr/bin` as suggested in some answers, I get: `changing ownership of '/usr/bin': Operation not permitted.`

I've found other similar questions/answers, such as: [get back sudo on ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16962/how-to-get-back-sudo-on-ubuntu) but I'm using Putty with Amazon EC2 web services, and they suggest in to reboot into user mode and then root. I don't know how to do that in Putty.

From what I read is kind of serious, so is the only option to detach my instance from the storage volume and start over again?

Comment: You could also switch to root using `su -` (giving the root user's password when asked for a password), then fix the issue and `exit`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but with EC2 I don't really use a password, I use a keychain (a file stored in my computer) to access every time, from there the confusion on how to fix this problem.

Comment: I nope no-one has really suggested `chown root:root /usr/bin`, as that's potentially a really bad idea. (Perhaps you've misread or mistyped the suggestion?) If you have a **root** password you should use the `su` approach suggested in your [apparent duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16962/100397). (You may not use it much, but you might have one given to you as part of the initial install.)

Comment: @roaima EC2 instances do not have root passwords, unless the customer changes that.  The default user is a passwordless sudoer.